# perl array size is smaller than it should be

Tags: arrays, perl

I want to initialize 4^9 (=262144) indices of @clump as 0. So I wrote this:

```
my $k=9;
my @clump=();
my $n=4**$k;
for(my $i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
   push(@clump,0);
   print "$i ";
}
```

But it keeps freezing at 261632! I then tried making $n=5^9 (=1953125) and my code stopped at 1952392. So its definitely not a memory issue. This should be simple enough but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Help a newbie?

Comment: Works fine here: `perl -E '$k=9; @clump=(); $n=4**$k; for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){ push(@clump,0)}'`

Comment: Works for me, as well.  Does `@clump = (0) x 4 ** $k` work for you?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to do with 4^9 zeros?

Comment: @Jim Davis -- @clump=(0)x 4**$k worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I'm writing a clump finding program using frequency arrays to find the ori site in Ecoli genome. For that I need to find the most frequent 9-nucleotide sequences in a genome file. The easiest way was to convert all possible sequences into corresponding array indices and +1 whenever the program encounters the sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $k = 9;
my $n = 4 ** $k;
my @clump = (0) x $n;

print join(' ', @clump), "\n";
printf "%d elements in \@clump\n", scalar @clump;
```

Or,

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $k = 9;
my $n = 4 ** $k;
my @clump;
$#clump = $n - 1;
$_ = 0 for @clump;

print join(' ', @clump), "\n";
printf "%d elements in \@clump\n", scalar @clump;
```

Output:

```
... 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
262144 elements in @clump
```

Also, note that initialization with `0` is almost never required in Perl. Why do you need this?

Comment: Your first suggestion worked. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 9):

[Suffering from buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html)?

When I add a `sleep 1000` to the end of your program, stream the output to a file, and read the tail of the file, I also observe the last numbers to be printed are 261632 and 1952392. The remaining output is stuck in the output buffer, waiting for some event (the buffer filling up, the filehandle closing, the program exiting, or an explicit flush call) to flush the output.

The buffering can be changed by one of the following statements early in your program

[`$|`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH)`= 1;`
`STDOUT->autoflush(1);`

Comment: Of course, rather than flushing after every a couple of characters, one might want to just use `print "\n";` after the loop, or `use IO::Handle; ... STDOUT->flush`.